# Launching Chrome Driver, but not able to do any actions?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run my webdriver tests in Chrome. Here are the steps I'm using to launch Chrome driver:

Set the chrome binary path

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "paht\\chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--start-maximized"));
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability("AcceptUntrustedCertificates", true);
capabilities.setCapability("AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer", true);
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--ignore-certificate-errors"));
driver = new ChromeDriver( capabilities);
```

My Chrome browser is launched, but its not running any tests, like open url etc?
Can some please assist me with the steps needed to launch working chromium browser

Answer (score 2):

You aren't going anywhere. You are literally just opening the browser and that's it.

Read the GettingStarted page here:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Essentially, you are looking for something like:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to download updated Chromedriver from this [link](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list)

```
    File file = new File("E://chromedriver.exe"); // set driver path 
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("http://google.com");
```

&

```
  public class chrome 
 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "E://chromedriver.exe"); //path of chrome driver
   WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   driver.get("http://www.google.com");

   }

  }
```

Check this code, it work for me.